# how do i parse this .csv data to json

Tags: javascript

I have a .csv file and it contains data that I want to use in processes.

```
date/time,"settlement id","type","order id","sku","description","quantity","marketplace","data","order city","order state","order postal","tax collection model","product sales","product sales tax","shipping credits","shipping credits tax","gift wrap credits","giftwrap credits tax","Regulatory fee","Tax on regulatory fee","promotional rebates","promotional rebates tax","marketplace withheld tax","selling fees","cargo fees","other transaction fees","other","total"
```

And I want to split them according to the rule.

- date/time : it is constantly being missed because there is no token at the beginning or end.
- The ' " ' 'mark at the end of others stays on all the time. I can't distinguish it. I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: Why is your question repeated twice?

Comment: Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question (and to share the results of that research in the question). It really shouldn't be hard to find [a way to parse CSV in JavaScript](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+csv+parser&t=h_&ia=web) or how to [turn the result into JSON](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+convert+object+to+json&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

You've pasted your question twice, might make it easier to understand if you fix that up :).

If the missing delimiter is a constant for all data, you can simply store it in a variable and add the required " characters to the start and end of the string. Then, you can process the variable as if it were valid .csv file, since the missing delimiter has now been added. This should make it easier to split and use the data in your processes.

Then to do CSV to JSON follow something like this:
http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, I did a lot of research before asking a question, but these codes could not split the data I had in the way I wanted. Thanks for your warning :)